# Python Apscheduler with processes (multiprocessing)

Tags: python, multiprocessing, apscheduler

I am trying to run processes (multiprocessing module) through the Apscheduler module

```
    sched = BackgroundScheduler(executors=executors)
    sched.add_listener(my_listener, EVENT_JOB_EXECUTED | EVENT_JOB_ERROR)
    #sched.add_job(run_processes, trigger='cron', hour='14', minute='06')
    sched.add_job(run_processes) # starts it a once
    sched.start()
```

run_processes looks like this

```
def run_processes():

print ("starting p1")
print ("starting p2")    
##run_process_1()
##run_process_2()
p1 = Process(target = run_process_1, args = ())
p2 = Process(target = run_process_2, args = ())

p1.start()
p2.start()

print p1, p1.is_alive()
print p2, p2.is_alive()
p1.join()
p2.join()
print ("finished")
```

When I start run_processes() without the Apscheduler it runs normal.
When I run it through the Apscheduler the processes seems to start (there are new Python instances), but then seem to wait or hang doing nothing.

Does anybody know of a problem there and possibly how to resolve it?

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish with multiprocessing? Wouldn't you rather use ProcessPoolExecutor (which APScheduler also uses internally when configured to do so)?

Comment: Also, you haven't even described the problem you're having.

Comment: I just tried ProcessPoolExecutor and got the same result. It hangs when using Apscheduler.